# Disable woocommerce short description

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How do I completely disable woocommerce short description? I'll like to do this without using CSS.

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

The Easiest  way would be just to leave the short description blank in the backend, however, if you're wanting to remove the short description panel in the backend, maybe try this:

```
function remove_short_description() {

remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt', 'product', 'normal');

}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'remove_short_description', 999);
```